# How do I get cli curl (7.47.0) to output raw text from a page?

Tags: curl

Long time reader first time questioner. So maybe my search fu is lacking, but I can't seem to find any reasonable help for this.

I have a little IoT device that has a small web server built into it. If I go to the page http://x.x.x.x/temp it will display the temp and humidity in plain text. I suspect this return is just raw unformatted text without HTML, and modern browsers add some needed html to display the results on their own. I believe this because if I view the source of the page there is just the text, but if I actually inspect the page I see some HTML. I am wanting to eventually grab this data and dump it into my database using curl in a perl script. I decided to make sure I could get the results I wanted from curl on the cli first. The trouble is curl returns nothing. I tried with wget too and also get nothing. Curl -v shows no return. Curl --trace-ascii - shows the response I am looking for, which I could probably deal with if I had to, but I would still like to know how to make it just dump what it receives as I would expect. Instead of having to parse/grep all that return from trace-ascii.

Browser output from the page:
[Browser grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jwWC.png)

CLI Output:

```
~$ curl http://192.168.11.7/temp -v
*   Trying 192.168.11.7...
* Connected to 192.168.11.7 (192.168.11.7) port 80 (#0)
> GET /temp HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.11.7
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Connection: close
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

curl with --trace-ascii:

```
~$ curl http://192.168.11.7/temp --trace-ascii -
== Info:   Trying 192.168.11.7...
== Info: Connected to 192.168.11.7 (192.168.11.7) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 80 bytes (0x50)
0000: GET /temp HTTP/1.1
0014: Host: 192.168.11.7
0028: User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
0041: Accept: */*
004e: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: Content-Type: text/html
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Connection: close
<= Recv header, 32 bytes (0x20)
0000: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: DHT22,.80.60.,.64.30.   <----- Output I would expect
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have also tried tweaking some of the headers trying to force different returns, and changing to the user agent. Both to no avail. I'm not sure the device has that sophisticated of a web server. For those wondering this is a WI02 from PrivateEyePi - https://ha.privateeyepi.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=66&product_id=127

Comment: OK, something very odd now, if I tell curl not to buffer the output, using the -N switch, it will attempt to output, meaning it will display the temp for a second, and then curl erases the output it was just displaying and returns nothing. I'm beginning to think there is a non-printing code in the return from the server, like a \b or something that is causing it to display, then erase the line.. Maybe?

Comment: OK, so now I need help understanding what is going on here. I tell it to output to a file with -o, and it download 21 bytes. The file is 21 bytes. If I cat the file, there is nothing displayed. If I open the file with vim, the output is there, it looks like it's sort of using windows line endings, but not completely.. I would think cat would still print those though. 

    DHT22,^M81.50^M,^M82.20^M

At the bottom of vim is says the file is [noeol] not sure what that means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the return from the device is including some ^M carriage returns in it. This is apparently confusing several linux programs, probably because that is a Windows line ending. I've reach out the developer of the device and hopefully this will be addressed in a future upgrade. There is a newer firmware I will be trying to see if it resolves the issue. Until then I guess I'm just going to have to grab the output via --trace-ascii.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
curl -iH "Accept: text/plain" http://192.168.11.7/temp
```

If that doesn't' work give a try to check what is the output by using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) `nc`:

```
echo -en "GET /temp HTTP/1.0\n\n\n" | nc 192.168.11.7 80
```

If using HTTP/1.1 the host will be required:

```
echo -en "GET /temp HTTP/1.1\nHost: 192.168.11.7\n\n" | nc 192.168.11.7 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that also returns no output from the page. The netcat doesn't return anything, which is odd because I can curl just the main page of the device and I get some return, so nc should have returned something. To get that specific string of text it has to GET the /temp url though.

Comment: What about `echo -en "GET /temp HTTP/1.0\n\n\n" | nc 192.168.11.7 80` notice the `/temp`,  regarding curl do you have something in `.curlrc` ? probably an user-agent?

Comment: Oddly it still just returns nothing.. I am beginning to suspect this 'web server' is not very standards compliant. I tested that nc should work just by hitting another website and it does. I do not have .curlrc or anything in /etc referring to curl from what I can tell.

Comment: try http 1.1 `echo -en "GET /temp HTTP/1.1\n\n\n" | nc ...` that seems to response from curl when using the ` --trace-ascii -` option

Comment: Same results. I even tried 2.0 and 4.01 (which I saw in the source of the return using chrome), and still no output from nc.

Comment: mmm `telnet X.X.X.X 80` at least connect you? `Escape character is '^]'.` in case you found the solution to this problem please post it, I am curious

Comment: It connects and immediately disconnect. I as I mentioned in a comment to my question -N switch gives some interesting results. I dump to a file with -o and it downloads 21 bytes, and the file is 21 bytes, but is totally blank..